# trying to do custom validation for three input fields linked to each other

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to write a javascript validation and if statement to represent the following:

> Field 1 can be entered and submitted on its own.
>
> Field 2 can be entered but if that is the case then Field 3 must also
>   be entered and then fields 1, 2 and 3 can be submitted or just Fields
>   2 and 3 with out Field 1.
>
> Field 3 if it is entered according to the last sentence must also
>   include Field 2.

*Which VAR's do I select all three of them for the one validation?*

**This is what I have written so far:**

```
function DoCustomValidation()
{
var first = document.forms["readings"] ["GlucoseLevel"].value;
var second = document.forms["readings"] ["SBP"].value;
var third = document.forms["readings"] ["DBP"].value;

if (
```

I know how to and where to create and put the validation in my .PHP file etc its just I am having a hard time writing the if else statement as its been a while for me with java and I have lost my touch.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: To verify that I understand your rules . .  
The valid submissions are Field 1 (without 2 or 3), Fields 2 and 3 (without 1), Fields 1, 2, and 3?
The invalid submissions are Fields 1 and 2 (but not 3) and Fields 1 and 3 (but not 2)?

Comment: errm yes I think that is it, just to clarify field 1 on its own is fine fields 2 and 3 on its own is fine and all 3 fields are fine. @post_erasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as stripped down as I can make it.

```
function DoCustomValidation()
{
    var first = document.forms["readings"] ["GlucoseLevel"].value;
    var second = document.forms["readings"] ["SBP"].value;
    var third = document.forms["readings"] ["DBP"].value;

    if(!second==!third){
        if(!first===false){
            return true;
        }
        else if (!second===false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: Add Messages
If you want messages on when the form fails to submit, try this

```
function DoCustomValidation()
{
    var first = document.forms["readings"] ["GlucoseLevel"].value;
    var second = document.forms["readings"] ["SBP"].value;
    var third = document.forms["readings"] ["DBP"].value;

    if(!second==!third){
        if(!first===false){
            return true;
        }
        else if (!second===false){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            alert("You cannot submit a blank form.");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("The SBP and DBP must both be blank or both be filled.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

That written, I don't advise using alerts (and that particular text) for your validations messages, but that's the best I can do without more information.

Comment: OK I will try this and include my error messages because the other guys I think is for submission and it is not really doing anything is is just being bypassed thanks I will report back my results @post_erasmus

Comment: Yes I won't use alert I have a custom validation script which will take care of the error messages and I will have them integrated on to the page itself thanks a lot am trying this now @post_erasmus

Comment: OK it is working that you can not submit a blank form and you can not leave on SBP or SBP blank but if I leave both 2 and 3 blank and just try to submit glucose (field 1) it won't work. @post_erasmus

Comment: @JatinderSingh Double check your implementation.  I've got it working at the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/KLWSd/2/.

Comment: yh I messed around with it the return true; statements where missing to pass it on and now it is working fine, thanks a lot! @post_erasmus

Comment: @JatinderSingh D'oh!  I've updated my answer to include those pesky return values.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do the trick the if second and third is to send if both have values even if first doesn't have, then you just have one more chose if first has a value and the other two are empty

```
function DoCustomValidation()
{
    ...
    if(second !="" && third != ""){
        //form submit
        return;
    }
    if(first != "" && second == "" && third == ""){
        //form submit
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to do the actual submit but show an error message before the submit indicating that 2 & 3 must be both filled or just field 1. I will try and modify your code to do just that, wish me luck as I am quite rusty and thanks anyway @bloody_demon